# Python 2.6:Trying to run an if statement if variable is a list

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm new to python and trying to complete an exercise where I print every variable from a list including any nested lists.

My issue is I can't get the nested lists to be recognised as lists by an if statement.

When I run type(i) it returns that it is a list however when I run `if type(i) is list` or `if type(i) == list` it fails to execute.

When I tried using `if isinstance(type(i), list)` I get a `TypeError:isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types.`

When I tried `isinstance(type(i),collections.Sequence)` the nested list isn't recognised as a list either.

If anyone has any advice it'd be appreciated. I'm using Python 2.6 as I'm following the MIT course.

Thanks

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import collections

listval= ["war",1,["brie","rocky","roq le coq"],[1,2,3]]

def printlist2(lists):
    for i in lists:
        print("Variable value: ", type(i))
        print ("Is variable a list: ",isinstance(type(i),collections.Sequence))
        #print (isinstance(type(i),list))
        if isinstance(type(i),collections.Sequence):
            print ("This is a list")
            printlist2(i)
        elif type(i) == list:
            print ("This is a list")
        elif type(i) is int:
            #print ("String length is equal to ",len(str(i)))
            print ("i is equal to integer ",i)
        else:
            #print ("String length is equal to ",len(i))
            print ("i is equal to string ",i) 

printlist2(listval)
```

Comment: When using is instance you dont need type()

Comment: If you are new to python don't start with python 2.6. Python 2 reached its end of life last year. Use an uptodate version like 3.8 or 3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways of testing for a list.  Trying to use all of them at once is really confusing and unnecessary, especially for asking a question in a forum like this.  I would recommend using `isinstance`.  You just want to test against the object itself rather than taking the `type()` of it with `isinstance`

If you use that test or one of the alternate methods, the structure of your code works fine and you get exactly 2 lists pointed out during your run. Your input data isn't demonstrating the recursion very well, but if you add more levels of embedded lists, the code will handle it.  Here's a much simplified version of your code showing that using `isinstance` does work:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

listval= ["war",1,["brie","rocky","roq le coq"],[1,2,3]]

def printlist2(lists):
    for i in lists:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            print ("This is a list: " + str(i))
            printlist2(i)
        else:
            print ("This is not a list: " + str(i))

printlist2(listval)
```

Result:

```
This is not a list: war
This is not a list: 1
This is a list: ['brie', 'rocky', 'roq le coq']
This is not a list: brie
This is not a list: rocky
This is not a list: roq le coq
This is a list: [1, 2, 3]
This is not a list: 1
This is not a list: 2
This is not a list: 3
```

`type(i) == list1` and `type(i) is list` would work too.  Just pick one. This code will work with both Python 2 and Python 3. I agree with @Wombatz - use a recent version of Python 3.